# ¿Porqué el contender o div interno esta fuera del div exterior?

Tags: css, div

Al querer renderizar una lista de productos dentro de un contenedor, tengo dificultad para poder insertarlos ya que en la página la lista se muestra fuera del div, de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera que los productos este dentro del contenedor color gris,
este es el `render`.

```
<section>
                <div className="container-lista">
                    <div className='columna-lista'>
                        <h2>Lista</h2>
                        <br></br>
                        <div className='lista'>
                        {renderProductos(productos)}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

y los estilos.css

```
 .container-lista {h2{font-family: $oswald; font-size:4rem;          color:darkcyan; background-color:lightgray; width:50%;  
   height: 100rem; text-align: center;  }}

.columna-lista {  margin-left: 30%; position: relative}

.lista {background-color: salmon; width: 300px; 
text-align: center; position: absolute;}
```

Comment: Ese codigo no funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primera vista el error es sencillo, quítale a la clase **.lista**, el **position: absolute;**. Pero a falta de un código más funcional o real, no puedo darte más indicaciones.

Tienes una serie de fallas como:

- No es *className* es **class**
- La etiqueta **br** se usa sola y es vacía. Así: **< br />** o **< br >**.
- En el css no puedes usar un selector dentro de otro selector, me refiero a que usas:

> .container-lista {h2{font-family: ...

- Si te vas a referir a una etiqueta dentro del .container-lista, solo debes separarlas con un espacio. así:

```
.container-lista h2 {}
```

Lo otro es que aparte de que tú código no es 100% funcional, ni siquiera genera una reproducción eficaz del error que se te presenta, te aconsejo por favor acomodalo para poder darte una mejor respuesta. Puedes usar el boton de **fragmento JavaScript/HTML/CSS** o pulsando la combinación de teclas **Ctrl + M**. Buen día.